# How many sages are referred to in the badrayana vyasa's Brahma sutras?

Tags: vedanta, brahma-sutras, vyasa

I know badrayana at more than one place cites jaiminis view in Brahma sutras, but there were other sages who wrote sutras and smritis after the culmination of Mahabharata, like deval, kapila etc how many of them have been mentioned in Brahma sutras?

Answer (score 6):

Here are all the figures that Vyasa names in the Brahma Sutras other than himself (using the Sutra numbering [here](http://tinyurl.com/brahmasutras))

1. **Jaimini**: He's mentioned 17 times, starting in Adhyaya 1 Pada 2 Sutra 28:

   > According to Jaimini, there is no contradiction even in case of direct meditation.
2. **Asmarathya**: He's mentioned twice, starting in Adhyaya 1 Pada 2 Sutra 29:

   > According to Asmarathya, it is from the point of view of manifestation (that God is referred to as spatially limited).
3. **Badari**: He's mentioned four times, starting with Adhyaya 1 Pada 2 Sutra 30:

   > According to Badari (God is spoken of as spatially limited) on account of being meditated on.
4. **Audulomi**: He's mentioned three times, starting with Adhyaya 1 Pada 4 Sutra 21:

   > Audulomi says that (the statement about the identity of the individual soul and the supreme Self occurs in the beginning) since this state of identity comes to the soul when it departs from the body.
5. **Kasakritsna**: He's the author of the lost Devata Kanda Sutras, and he's mentioned once, in Adhyaya 1 Pada 4 Sutra 22:

   > Kasakritsna thinks (the statement about the identity in the beginning of the text is in order) because of the existence of the supreme Self as the individual soul.
6. **Karsnajini**: He's mentioned once, in Adhyaya 3 Pada 1 Sutra 9:

   > If it be contended that (the soul gets its rebirth) owing to conduct (and not residual karma), then according to Karsnajini, it is not so, that (Upanishadic passage) being used suggestively (for residual karma).

In any case, figures like Kapila are not mentioned in the Brahma Sutras, but the schools they founded are mentioned and refuted, see my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18850/36).

Comment: Are badri and badrayana two different people or is he just referring to himself in third person?

Comment: Yes, Badari and Badarayana (Vyasa) are two different people.  But Vyasa does refer to himself in the third person, that's why I said "Here are all the figures that Vyasa names in the Brahma Sutras other than himself."