# What are the arguments of vedanta sutras against pAshupata sect?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, pashupata-shaivism

Vedanta Sutras and its commentaries are said to be critical of pashupata sect.

I think the second chapter talks about this in detail.

What are the arguments raised against this school?

Comment: Discussed (see the point no 7) in the answer to : [What are all doctrines or philosophies discussed in Brahma Sutra?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16967/277)

Comment: @Pandya so is it the only those points mentioned in the answer ?

Answer (score 2):

Pashupata Shaivism is discussed and refuted in Adhyaya 2 Pada 2 Sutra 7 of the Vedanta Sutras:

> **Topic-7: God Is Not a Mere Superintendent**
>
> 37. For the Lord there can be no creatorship, for that leads to incongruity.
> 38. And (the incongruity arises) because of the impossibility of a relationship.
> 39. And (the position is untenable) because of the impossibility of (Nature) coming under (His) direction. (Or) And (God cannot be proved), since no physical support (adhisthana) is possible for Him.
> 40. Should it be argued that God will direct Nature like (a man directing) the organs, then it cannot be so, for that will result in God’s having experiences (of happiness, sorrow etc.). (Or) If a body, equipped with sense-organs, be assumed for God, (we say that) this is not possible; because of (consequent) experiences etc.
> 41. God will be subject to finitude or loss of omniscience.